# Random precision in the digits

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I am running Mathematica 12.3.1.0 under Windows 11 64-bit. Everything was running perfectly under Windows 10, until I updated to Windows 11.
Now, I type, for example,

k = 1.3807 10^-23

m = 1.3804 10^-23

h = 6.6261 10^-34

and get

1.3807000000000002*10^-23

1.3804*10^-23

6.626100000000001*10^-34

or when plotting, I get a lot of digits, either in the x-axis or the y-axis.
For example,

f = x^2 E^-x^2;
Plot[f, {x, -5, 5}]

gives me

[image]

I assume the problem comes from Windows, but is there a way to solve the problem?

My apologies if this has already been addressed, but I did not find it after searching.

Comment: Looks like you set `PrintPrecision` to a high value.

Comment: You could check your Preferences (Appearance > Numbers > Formatting on a Mac/M1). You can also check the setting with `Options[$FrontEnd, PrintPrecision]` or `Options[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision]`

Comment: Thanks, Michael. PrintPrecision was set to 40. If I change it to 6, numbers are displayed correctly, but that does not mean they are stored with the value I entered, just that they are shown only with 6 digits. It puzzles me that k and m, being almost identical, are shown with different number of digits. Also, the plot continues with the same problem, whatever number I set PrintPrecision to.