# Decrease decimal points in a plot

Tags: plotting

I wanna List plot data. The problem is in the y-axis, it shows unnecessary numbers of decimals. for example, instead of -0.8, it shows 0.80000000000. I tried FrameTicks, but the result is unaffected. [image]

I tried the following code.

`plot22 =  ListLinePlot[transpose, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-1.5, -0.5}}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLegends -> {"bsl6d"}, FrameTicks -> {{{-0.6, -0.8, -1.0, -1.2, -1.4, -1.8}, None}, {{20, 40, 60, 80, 100}, None}} ]`

I appreciate it if you could help me to fix it.

Comment: "transpose" is not defined

Comment: It is a {256, 2} List.

Comment: I can not reproduce your plot without some example data.

Comment: Does [@Michael E2's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283590/random-precision-in-the-digits) fix your problem? `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintPrecision -> 6]`

Comment: you need to include complete data to reproduce the plot. This will make it easier for someone to help you.

Comment: I would think coding the FrameTicks numbers as  `SetPrecision[-0.6,n]`  with $n$ and integer and so forth would work.